# How to show data in a div outside of the map whenever a marker is clicked in the map of mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Whenever a marker is clicked on the map I need to show data of that marker in a div which outside of the map.

I am trying with Html Dom element.

```
map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {
            var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
            var title = e.features[0].properties.title;
            var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

            while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
                coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
            }


            var content = '<div><strong>' + feature.properties.title + '</strong>' +
                '<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p></div>';

            info.innerHTML = content;

        });
```

This where I need to show information in a table.

```
 <div class="info" id="info" style="color: whitesmoke">


        </div>
```

This is the map div

```
<div id="map">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

`info.innerHTML = content;`

with this line:

`document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = content;`